# My .bash_profile is locked. How do I edit it?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm a bit new to this area on my Mac.  I made my .bash_profile yesterday without any problems.   Now when I open it, textedit says it's locked and does not let me unlock it.  I tried using chmod 644 to change the permissions, but that didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's a file that should require super user permissions, so use the `sudo` keyword, like `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give yourself write permissions for that file:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown yourusername /Users/yourusername/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I get this error chmod: /Users/duraiamuthan/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

Cypress Frankenfeld answered it in

[Cannot edit bash_profile on Mac OsX [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692100/cannot-edit-bash-profile-on-mac-osx)

> sudo chown your_user_name ~/.bash_profile